# Pickle will not save a list of objects (inside a class)

Tags: python

Inside a python class:

I have created a data class

```
@dataclass(slots=True)
class CellClass:
    fgcolor: str
    bgcolor: str
    text: str
    status: str
```

I have initialized a list

```
CellContentList = []
```

I have stored data class objects in the list

```
def InitializeCellContentList():
    for x in range(20):
        newitem = CellClass(fgcolor="black",bgcolor="lightgrey",
                            text="",status="unlocked")
    CellContentList.append(newitem)
```

I have written a function to save the list of objects using pickle

```
def WriteCellData():
    with open('CellData.pkl','wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(CellContentList,file)
```

And I am getting the following error (note: Mod is the name of the class)

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Mod.__init__.<locals>.CellClass'
```

All of the code works except the pickle function. The pickle function worked fine when I wrote the same application outside a class. But now, in re-writing the application inside a class, it no longer works. I am hoping that there is enough information in the error message that someone could point out what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "But now, in re-writing the application inside a class, it no longer works." - it sounds like you moved way too much stuff inside that class. That error message, with this code, sounds like all the code you just posted is nested inside a class's `__init__` method.

Comment: This isn't your problem, but your `append` in `InitializeCellContents` has the wrong indentation.  You'll only be appending one item to `CellContentList`.

Comment: You're going to have to be a little bit more clear.  What do you mean "the application is now inside a class".  What piece of the code above is now in a class? Can you show us your current code?  In particular, what is Mod?

Comment: You really must provide a [mcve]. For starters, the error message shows the class name to be `Mod.__init__.<locals>.CellClass`, so that implies that the class definition is *inside* `Mod.__init__`. This doesn't make any sense, there is no reason to do this, and you should just not do it. When you say " re-writing the application inside a class" I suspect you have a fundamental misunderstanding about class definitions, because that doesn't make any sense. It *sounds* like you've just written everything inside of some `class Mod` `__init__`, but again, that is just not what you should be doing

Comment: I cannot duplicate your problem.  The code you have above works perfectly and cretes a pickle.

Comment: All comments appreciated. I will try again, whittling things down to reproducible code.

Comment: Its that "Inside a python class" part as mentioned in other comments. When you define a class inside a function or method, that class is rebuilt and bound to the local variable each time the function is run. The class does not have a name reachable by pickle.